# Django save files under dynamic path based on ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Project():
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class Task():
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    project = models.ForeignKey('prosystem.Project',
                                related_name='tasks',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class TaskFile(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=self.make_file_path())        # I want this to be dynamic path

    def make_file_path(self):
       # pseudocode, does not work
       pid = self.task.project.id
       tid = self.task.id
       path = f'project_{pid}/task_{tid}/'
       return path
```

I want to upload files to a folder based on its `Task` id and its parent `Project` id. How can I do that?

Comment: This looks to me like a very bad idea: imagine that the name of the `Task` or `Project` changes its name, then this will require all sorts of extra logic (and there are ways in the Django ORM to bypass this logic) to *rename* the file. In my opinion, the filename on the *server* is not that relevant. You better ensure that on the *frontend* the filename is *presented* with a "nice" name.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem but I am talking about a *path* to a file, not its *name*. Are there any differences to what you have written in that case?

Comment: no, since a path is in essence nothing more than a *sequence* of names (so the above stated problem holds).

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem ok thank you about that notatation, I will think about that. But if I agree with that - any advices how to build that path as I want?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem btw, changed naming from using simple *name* to models' *id* fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
class Project():
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class Task():
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    project = models.ForeignKey('prosystem.Project',
                                related_name='tasks',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def make_file_path(instance, filename):

   pid = instance.task.project.id
   tid = instance.task.id
   path = f'project_{pid}/task_{tid}/{filename}'

   return path

class TaskFile(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks')

    # Please note that "()" have been removed here. You don't want to
    # give the result of make_file_path() but the function itself
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=make_file_path)
```

For more information, refer to the [documentation about FileField.upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

Comment: will `def make_file_path` be a part of `TaskFile` model?

Comment: No, it's a global function, defined in the module. You can put it anywhere you want as long as you correctly import it

Comment: You may declare `make_file_path` inside your model, but in such case you will need to declare it as `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`

Comment: if I use it with `classmethod` - should i add `cls` as first argument?

Comment: and how can I use this method inside field? prepended with `self.`? Pycharm shows me bad syntax now.

Comment: Yes, with class method you have to use `cls` as first arg. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669524/1887976) for more and complete information. Use the method with `TaskFile.make_file_path` from your model field declaration

Comment: this works with global function, thank you. If you can - just update your answer with id_strings instead of names, as I have updated my question - for convenience of future readers.

Comment: I updated my answer with the new path syntax you provided

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `CustomFileStorage` and add it to your file field.
Info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-file-storage/)